# jQuery Cookie Plugin reading Value

Tags: jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I want this thing working, but I don't know how.

I want to show a banner if a cookie is set and the value of the cookie matches.

Actually I can read the cookie but not the value. If the cookie exists the banner shows up - this one is done. But the banner should show up if the cookie exists and the value matches.

These are the cookie informations:

This one should match an show the banner:

Name: myCookie 
Value: a%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A17%3A%22bmbankloginBankId%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A27%3A%22bmbankloginDisclaimerSigned%22%3Bb%3A1%3B%7D
Host: www.mydomain.de
Path: /
Expires: Wed, 30 Dec 2043 23:26:25 GMT

The same cookie with an other value, wich should not show up the banner in the end:

Name: myCookie 
Value: a%3A2%3A%7Bs%3A17%3A%22bmbankloginBankId%22%3Bs%3A2%3A%2229%22%3Bs%3A27%3A%22bmbankloginDisclaimerSigned%22%3Bb%3A1%3B%7D
Host: www.mydomain.de
Path: /
Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2043 08:57:36 GMT

This is my script:

```
<div id="partner" class="position_helper_banner"><a href="http://www.google.de/" target="_blank" title="something"><img src="partner-banner-180x73.png" /></a></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  if($.cookie('myCookie')) {
    $('#partner').show();
  }
});
</script>
```

Via CSS is #partner set to display:none.

The jQuery Plugin contains this:

```
/*!
 * jQuery Cookie Plugin v1.3.1
 * https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie
 *
 * Copyright 2013 Klaus Hartl
 * Released under the MIT license
 */
(function (factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        // AMD. Register as anonymous module.
        define(['jquery'], factory);
    } else {
        // Browser globals.
        factory(jQuery);
    }
}(function ($) {

    var pluses = /\+/g;

    function decode(s) {
        if (config.raw) {
            return s;
        }
        return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(pluses, ' '));
    }

    function decodeAndParse(s) {
        if (s.indexOf('"') === 0) {
            // This is a quoted cookie as according to RFC2068, unescape...
            s = s.slice(1, -1).replace(/\\"/g, '"').replace(/\\\\/g, '\\');
        }

        s = decode(s);

        try {
            return config.json ? JSON.parse(s) : s;
        } catch(e) {}
    }

    var config = $.cookie = function (key, value, options) {

        // Write
        if (value !== undefined) {
            options = $.extend({}, config.defaults, options);

            if (typeof options.expires === 'number') {
                var days = options.expires, t = options.expires = new Date();
                t.setDate(t.getDate() + days);
            }

            value = config.json ? JSON.stringify(value) : String(value);

            return (document.cookie = [
                config.raw ? key : encodeURIComponent(key),
                '=',
                config.raw ? value : encodeURIComponent(value),
                options.expires ? '; expires=' + options.expires.toUTCString() : '', // use expires attribute, max-age is not supported by IE
                options.path    ? '; path=' + options.path : '',
                options.domain  ? '; domain=' + options.domain : '',
                options.secure  ? '; secure' : ''
            ].join(''));
        }

        // Read
        var cookies = document.cookie.split('; ');
        var result = key ? undefined : {};
        for (var i = 0, l = cookies.length; i < l; i++) {
            var parts = cookies[i].split('=');
            var name = decode(parts.shift());
            var cookie = parts.join('=');

            if (key && key === name) {
                result = decodeAndParse(cookie);
                break;
            }

            if (!key) {
                result[name] = decodeAndParse(cookie);
            }
        }

        return result;
    };

    config.defaults = {};

    $.removeCookie = function (key, options) {
        if ($.cookie(key) !== undefined) {
            // Must not alter options, thus extending a fresh object...
            $.cookie(key, '', $.extend({}, options, { expires: -1 }));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    };

}));
```

So what should I do??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page loads for the first time (or whenever) set the cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });
```

On subsequent loads grab it's value (it'll be undefined if not set):

```
var cookieValue = $.cookie('the_cookie');
```

Then decide what to do:

```
var requiredValue = "whatever";
if(cookieValue === requiredValue){
  $('#partner').show();
}
```

**EDIT:**

Something like this:
    $.cookie.json = true;

```
var cookieValue = {
  value1: "string",
  value2: integer,
  value3: {object}
}

$.cookie('my_cookie', cookieValue, { expires: 7, path: '/' });

var cookieValue = $.cookie('the_cookie'),
    requiredValue = "whatever";

if(cookieValue[key] === requiredValue){
  $('#partner').show();
}
```

Comment: Great, this works! Thanx!
But the value of the cookie is a kind of an array (I think) and theres only one parameter which is the indicator I'm searching for. This is the array: "a:2:{s:17:"bmbankloginBankId";s:1:"1";s:27:"bmbankloginDisclaimerSigned";b:1;}" - I'm only looking for ""bmbankloginBankId";s:1:"1";". What should I do? Thanx a lot!!!!

Comment: The value of the cookie is a string (unless you specify `$.cookie.json = true`). If you have to store all of that info you list, stick it in an object, save it as such and reference accordingly once you retrieve it.

Comment: Thanx, but I don't know how to do that. Could you give me another hint, please?